# If I run out of memory, which process will be killed?

Tags: memory, crash

I have an important process which I don't want to be killed. This process is using about 10GB of RAM. I have 32GB available. I want to run another process which will take up 18.2GB of RAM. There should be some room left. What happens if I hit the full 32GB? Will the last program I called be killed? That wouldn't be so bad, but the important one cannot die.

Answer (score 0):

It is a likely chance that one of your programs will be moved to your disk but i'm not sure which one it is so I recommend batch processing.

Comment: I need all the data in main memory at the same point because I am sorting it. Is there a variant of merge sort which would work? Do you know of any implementations?